# Creating a WARP device in managed DirectX

Tags: directx, graphics

I have a very old graphic card that only supports shader model 2, but I need shader model 3 or up for the app I am developing. I tried to use a reference device but it seems to run very slowly, then I found some samples in C++ that allows me to change to a WARP device and the performance is good. I am using C# and I don't know how to create such type of device. 
So the question is: how do I create a WARP device in C#?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider dropping $50 on a cheap video card made in the last decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed DirectX is a D3D9 based API. WARP is a D3D10+ only technology. You might want to look at other managed DirectX wrappers that support D3D10+, these should be able to use WARP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using SlimDX and DX11, and I already found the way. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option if you want to stick with MDX use to use Windows 8.

In Windows 8 D3D9 falls back to WARP when there's no hardware device, so you can disable your graphics card in device manager to switch to WARP.

Comment: Good to know, but if I have to make a move, I prefer SlimDX to Windows 8 (I'm a W7 user). Thanks for the answer.